# Open vs delimited writing areas

Tags: interface, text-editor

What's more comfortable to the user? Open, unobstructive writing areas:

[image]

Or enclosed ones:

[image]

Also, I wonder if the absence of delimiting borders makes users feel 'overwhelmed' (because there's too much empty space)?

**EDIT:**

How about those with high contrast?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion **would be to go for the third option** since it helps establish the contrast for the writing area and helps the user focus on the content he is writing.

[image]

The issue I have with #1 is that the writing section is the same color as the content on the left hand side and the lack of contrast makes it hard for the user to differentiate between the sidebar and the writing area.

While #2 is better, the contrast of the writing area is not strong enough and hence the user could get distracted by the subtle differences in color.

Remember **your focus should be on ensuring a distraction focus experience for your users so that users can perform the primary task of the application**. Here are [some examples of distraction free writing applications](http://lifehacker.com/5689579/five-best-distraction-free-writing-tools)

Also to [quote this article](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/how-create-distraction-free-reading-web-9134550) which talks about why there should be minimal distractions during writing

> In 2011 WordPress released a feature called Distraction Free Writing.
>   Eliminating WordPress settings, options and other distractions,
>   leaving you with a blank canvas to lay your words upon. Ridding
>   yourself of all the attributes of the edit post screen helps you write
>   faster, and with better clarity.

Comment: Thanks! If you were to spend hours writing, which one would you choose?

Comment: Definitely the third one.

Comment: I wonder if not having delimiting borders make the user feel 'overwhelmed' (too much empty space)?

Comment: many tools have distraction free options, Sublime Text for example, but also full screen mode in a browser could be considered to be the same, my DJ software, Rane Serato DJ actually loads in this state as the default too

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question:

1) #1 is too loose definitely, no real visual difference between each section.

2) #3 gives more a sensation of "falling" visually in the middle of the page, it can be good for some people, but not for everyone. Some people could feel it a little enclosed.

So, between #2 and #3, I wouldn't be 100% sure.

Now, my suggestions:

3) I don't know if the "Animal Suicide" text has that light background just for error (like it was selected when you take the screenshot), but if it's not, it should be the same color as the section background.

4) **Let users choose**. In the user options, or in the same page with a discrete href text, you can change the styles. You can give them some optioms or make it fully configurable.
Also think about those who write at night, and maybe doesn't want the 100% white background to burn their eyes. That would be an useful option.

5) Make it even less distracting. If you choose #2, make text a bit lighter (closest to the background) to lose some contrast there => less distraction.
The same with the #3, you could make the text darker.
 Then on hover, you could switch to a style like the one in your images, with more contrast.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you're asking about a solely greyscale theme here as that's what you've posted.)

The third one is horrible.  The bold background clamors for your attention in your peripheral view.

The second looks like one of the overly subtle "steel" themes that Apple imposed on us in their recent OSes where you can't tell what's selected vs. what's not.  The shaded background only serves to make it more difficult to read the text printed on it.

Of the choices, I'd go with the first, but bold the current selection in the right sidebar instead of shading.  Use a 2 pixel wide grey line to denote the edges of the writing area if you really think you need to demark the zone.

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer by outlining **why** you chose the first option.